# Chasles relation for Dirac mass

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I am trying to analyze an expression involving integration of distributions. And I want to generalize a result to discrete ones. While doing so I remarked the following issue.

Denote by $\delta_1$ the Dirac mass at $1$ and let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$.
We first have the relation,
$$
\int_0^2 f(x) d \delta_1 = f(1).
$$
Moreover, by Chasles,
$$
\int_0^2 f(x) d \delta_1 = \int_0^1 f(x) d \delta_1 + \int_1^2 f(x) d \delta_1.
$$

**Question:** What is the value of each integral on the right hand side? Is there some convention about endpoints for Dirac integration I am not aware of ?

I hope this question is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $\int_a^b$ hides the detail whether the integration region is an open , half-open, or closed intervall. Usually this is of no importance, since sets with one element have Lebesgue measure zero. This is not the case for the measure $\delta_1$. So when splitting the integral, we have to be more careful:
$$
\int_{[0,2]} f(x) d\delta_1 = \int_{[0,1]} f(x) d\delta_1  + \int_{(1,2]} f(x) d\delta_1 = 0 + f(1).
$$